# Blazor On Parent Click then Check Child Checkbox

Tags: blazor

This is what my html currently looks like.

```
<div class="form-check" @onclick="ChangeCheckboxState">
    <input type="checkbox" id="isActive" class="form-check-input" bind="@MyModel.Active" checked />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="isActive">Is Active?</label>
</div>
```

What I can't figure out how to do in blazor is on click for '.form-check' then check the child checkbox. Its easy using Javascript and/or JQuery. I am trying to avoid using JS if Blazor can handle it without too much hassle but doesn't seem to be possible.

I am using the code behind approach, creating a subclass of ComponentBase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your problem, but...

You should add `@bind` instead of just `bind`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="isActive" class="form-check-input" @bind="MyModel.Active" checked />
```

And do

```
void ChangeCheckboxState(){
    MyModel.Active = !MyModel.Active;
}
```

Comment: I also needed to change bind to @bind and remove the @ for the property.  @bind="MyModel.Active"

Comment: @Grim added it to the question